# SQL queries with different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I try to join over one field and it gives me different results in two queries that should give same results. Queries are:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomer tca
WHERE tca.PhoneNumber IN(
    SELECT ts.SubscriptionNumber FROM sub.tblSubscription ts
    WHERE ts.ServiceTypeID=4
    AND ts.SourceID=-1
)
```

and

```
SELECT tca.*
FROM   sub.tblSubscription ts
       inner JOIN tblCustomer tca
            ON  ts.SubscriptionNumber = tca.PhoneNumber
WHERE  ts.ServiceTypeID = 4
       AND ts.SourceID = -1
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What is difference? Relationship is one-to-one or another?

Comment: can you show us the data and the table definitions please?

Comment: `IN` is a semi join and won't bring in duplicates due to the `1..n` relationship. It is more efficient than inner joining then removing the duplicates with `DISTINCT`

Comment: One subscription can have multiple customer records because subscription number is phone number so one phone number can be with a multiple customers over time so its Subscription(1) to Customer(many) relation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming a customer can have multiple subscriptions, right? Let's assume you have 5 customers, each with 2 subscriptions...

When doing a SELECT ... FROM Customer WHERE IN (Subscription), you will receive 5 customer records, because each of those 5 customers are in fact in the subscription table, even though the subscription table will have 10 records. You are inherently asking the database for the data from one table, where the value of one of it's fields exists in another table. So it will only return the distinct records in the FROM table, irrespective of the amount of data in the WHERE IN table.

On the other hand, INNER JOINing the Customer table with the subscription table will return 5 customers x 2 subscriptions each = 10 records. By JOINing the tables you are asking the database for ALL the data in each table, where the data is matched up against specific fields.

So yes, the 2 queries will definitely give you different results.

Comment: It is Subscription(1) to Customers(many) relation, so it should give the same results

Comment: @stanke - So provide a repro showing us the different results.

Comment: @MartinSmith I found out that inner join is duplicating results, as you said, so when I do 'distinct' in the query with inner join it gives me same results as in 'where...in' query. So thanks a lot!

Comment: So the relationship can't be Subscription(1) to Customers(many) then (that doesn't make sense anyway and must be the wrong round? Can multiple customers really share the same subscription?)

Comment: Yes they can. Say you have some phone number 1234567 and you use it, then you change phone and you get new number and old number get recycled and some other customer gets it, or you simple transfer phone from you to your relative and you have one subscription(identified with a phone number) and two customer records for that subscription